# How to find whether a stored procedure exists on a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I want to check whether a stored procedure exists on a linked server.

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(
    [DBMSSQL\MSSQL2008R2], 
    'select * from [db1].sys.objects where type=''P'' and name=''procedure1'''
)
```

Comment: where do i need to give database name ?

Comment: what database? from where? Please provide a more details

Comment: 'select * from sys.objects where type=''P'' and name=''procedure1'''. This query executes in master db of linked server. But my stored procedure exists in another DB.

Comment: just add `[your_db].` before `sys.objects`